# VS c# WebBrowser resize

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, webbrowser-control

I am using VS2015 and have a WebBrowser on a panel in a form which is anchored to each side of the panel. 
I have coded the ability to enlarge the panel and hence the browser control (on a panel) when double clicked by attaching an eventhandler. 
This all works well and when initially displayed (small window 300x150) the google map that it displays via a document.write with the example HTML + Javascript provided by google, fits neatly in the window. 
When I enlarge the webbrowser by enlarging the panel webPanel.size = new size(1000, 500); and reload the page using document.write the map (image) that it retrieves is still 300x150 and tiles to fill the control.

Any ideas how to fix this.

As far as I can see the PreferedSize of the browser control remains at 300x150. Is this being used to request the size of the map image?

How does PreferedSize change?

Cheers,
Wayne

Comment: Surely you mis-identified the problem.  The Google Maps zoom rate does not depend on the size of the browser window.  Something you can easily see by using a regular browser and changing its window size.  All it does is pan the map to keep the target location centered.

Comment: No, When I first display the map in the smaller box I can only zoom out until the map can not be made any smaller without duplicating parts of it, then it doesn't allow any more zooming. When I enlarge the box with the same HTML/JS I can then keep zooming out until I get a view with 8 of the smaller maps tiled and a grey bar at the top and bottom.It looks like it is still retrieving the smaller image and tiling it to fill the box.

Comment: OK so it looks like the problem lies with the actual map retrieved from Google as using the same HTML/Script in Chrome produces the same results. Either there is an option missing or I have to limit zoom levels in code somehow.

Comment: I have kind of fixed it. I needed to adjust the JavaScript to resize the zoom and bounds of the map to keep it on screen at a reasonable size.